# How to draw a histogram when some bins dominate the others

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I would like to draw a histogram that explains how the data is distributed. My problem is that most of the data have very small values. Hence, if you use 10 bins, it won't be so descriptive; most of the data squeeze in 0.0-0.1 bin. If you use 1000 bins, then histogram does not look good because of the xlabels
and some bins overlap the others since we have too much bins.

I tried to use such as log-scale, normalized version as well but still I couldn't get an informative histogram. I have already calculated the (1000) bins and the counts. The code for reading the data is below. You can run it: `./sub-histogram.py hist-data.txt 2500 0`. 0 means you use the raw counts (first line). The last line contains the bin values.

First idea is to merge counts and bins with some threshold. If the counts smaller than some threshold, accumulate this count and skip this bin. I don't have any further idea right now, but I am sure that if you use histogram you've come across this issue. Is there
any solution for such cases? Data and everything is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3482709/histogram-q.tar).

```
import sys
from itertools import izip
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

lines = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()
threshold = float(sys.argv[2])
count_type = int(sys.argv[3]) # 0 for raw counts, 1 for normalized counts, 2 for log counts

# reading 
C = map(float, lines[count_type][1:-2].replace(",", "").split())
B = map(float, lines[3][1:-2].replace(",", '').split())

# merging method. 
# accumulate the counts with respect to threshold.
counts = []
bins = []
ct = 0
for c, b in izip(C,B):
    ct += c
    if ct >= threshold:
        counts.append(ct)
        bins.append(b)
        ct = 0

if ct > 0:
    counts.append(ct)
    bins.append(b)
    ct = 0

print counts
print bins

bar_width= 0.005
plt.xticks(np.linspace(0,2,41))
plt.bar(bins, counts, bar_width)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried log but bars overlapping with each other even I used width of a bar 0.005. Plan B is using the log but I would like to hear some thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a number of bins for your small values and a bigger than bin e.g. 100 bins for values in the range 0.000 to 0.200 with an interval of 0.002 and one bin for everything over 0.200, (you could possibly have 10 bins for 0.000-0.009, ten for 0.010-0.090, etc.,), you will then need to override the labels on the X-axis but `ax.set_xticklabels` lets you do that.

Comment: Steve, thanks for the answer. I created the bins `bins = np.linspace(0, 0.009, 10).tolist() + np.linspace(0.01, 0.09, 10).tolist() + np.linspace(0.1, 1, 2).tolist()`. Now, I need to iterate over all values and add each value into the right bin. But how can I make plt do all this stuff? (I don't understand `ax.set_xticklabels` by the way. What is `ax`?)

Comment: By the way, the code above does the similar thing with not fixed bins but with a threshold. However, it does not look well.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html gives you a demo of using custom axis labels for bar charts.